# Convert time result to single digit value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with SQL Server. I have a SQL query like this:

```
select 
    t.TBarcode, l.Timeinterval 
from 
    Transaction_tbl t  
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Location_tbl l ON t.Locid = l.Locid
```

getting result like this:

```
 Tbarcode   Timeinterval:
   1         00:10:00
   2         00:05:00
   3         00:20:00
```

Instead of this `timeinterval` I want to get my `timeinterval` output like this:

```
Timeinterval:
 10
 05
 20
```

What changes do I have to make in my query to get this result?

Comment: time interval will come only i minutes??

Comment: What does `01:23:05` give you?

Comment: what is the sql type for `l.Timeinterval`?

Comment: @user3106114- but what kind of digits you want as time interval??? Please specify.... I mean only minutes or all??

Comment: only minutes i want to show after executing query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `SQL Datatype` of `l.TimeInterval` is `datetime` or `time` then

:

```
select t.TBarcode,  CAST(DATEPART(minute,l.Timeinterval) as varchar(2))
from Transaction_tbl t  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location_tbl l ON t.Locid = l.Locid
```

Comment: sir my TimeInterval  is datatype of time(0)..so how can i write

Answer (score 1):

if TimeInterval is date, you could use `DATEDIFF`.

[DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @dat time(0) = GETDATE()
SELECT @dat 
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(@dat, 5), 2)
```